# JavaScript fetching values from div tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I'm new to JavaScript. I need to fetch value 'KARTHIK' from the following code using document.getElement,

```
<div class="account-info">
<h3 class="account-header">Welcome back,</h3>
<p>
<strong>KARTHIK</strong><br> 
</p>
</div>
```

Any one help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem with selecting element or is it changing text of selected element?

Comment: There is no such method `document.getElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

you just have to give the strong tag an id.

```
<strong id="ih">KARTHIK</strong>
<script>var innerStrong=document.getElementById("ih").innerHTML;</script>
```

Comment: Just a tip, you might want to assign a more intuitive `id` than `"ih"` :)

Comment: Is there any other alternative without assigning id?

Comment: Yes there is. you can give it a class name then use `Document.getElementsByClassName`. or if you don't want to give the `<strong>` tag any thing you can type `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];` . you will need to type [0] since `getElementsByTagName` returns the array of all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by its tag:

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="account-info">
<h3 class="account-header">Welcome back,</h3>
<p>
<strong>KARTHIK</strong><br> 
</p>
</div>
```

However, get elements by the tag name can be unreliable, because there may be more than one `<strong>` tag. Thus, it would be advisable to assign an `id` to the element:

```js
alert(document.getElementById("account-name").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="account-info">
<h3 class="account-header">Welcome back,</h3>
<p>
<strong id="account-name">KARTHIK</strong><br> 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this won't work as you are applying `innerHTML` on a `Nodelist`

Comment: Click "Run code snippet" above, and see what happens... don't downvote unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I have removed -1 as you have edited the answer, and you should accept your mistakes instead of running from them

Comment: @Ankit that was a typo, I forgot a parentheses and a `[0]`. Obviously that was a minor error that I overlooked by accident and **fixed before you commented**.

Comment: I don't want to fuel this pointless discussion, but you made your edit at `2015-04-14 04:11:08Z`, while the comment by @Ankit was posted at `2015-04-14 04:10:52Z`.

Comment: @FelixKling, on my computer it appeared after my edit, but honestly, even I can't edit my question in 16 seconds :)

Comment: The time when the comment was made and when you saw it can be different. Comments don't propagate instantly, there is at least a network delay and SO might check for new comments ever X seconds only ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector of document object to get this easily.

`document.querySelector("div.account-info strong").innerHTML`

Refer this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yurogofosa/1/)